# Streaming Audio Using the AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avplayer

I want to use the AVPlayer to stream audio, I only want to stream single tracks so not bothered about queuing. Does anyone know of any good examples online of how to do this. I'm also not to bothered about track time but will need to know it when it is ready to play, and if get interrupted etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple demo is good for what you are asking:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101